# max_element() is giving very weird error messages

Tags: c++

While learning c++, I'm attempting to make a rock-paper-scissors bot that (in a very stupid way) might discover any patterns in the opposing player.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int check_winner(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (b - a == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (b - a == -2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int bot_choice = rand() % 3 + 1;
    int user_choice = 0;
    bool run = true;
    array<int, 3> rocks = {0,0,0};
    array<int, 3> papers = {0,0,0};
    array<int, 3> scissors = {0,0,0};
    int last_choice = 0;
    while (run == true) {
        if (last_choice == 0) {
            bot_choice = std::distance(rocks.begin(), std::max_element(rocks,rocks.end()));
        }
        cout << "Enter your choice from 1 to 3, or enter 0 for exiting ";
        cin >> user_choice;
        system("read");
        if (user_choice == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            if (last_choice == 0) {
                rocks[user_choice] += 1;
            }
            else if (last_choice == 1) {
                papers[user_choice] += 1;
            }
            else {
                scissors[user_choice] += 1;
            }
            last_choice = user_choice;
            cout << "Bot chose " << bot_choice << "\n";
            if (check_winner(user_choice,bot_choice) == 0) {
                cout << "User won!\n";
            }
            else if (check_winner(user_choice,bot_choice) == 1) {
                cout << "Bot won!\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Draw!\n";
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Whenever I try to run the code, the following error message appears:

```
learning_rps.cpp:30:55: error: no matching function for call to 'max_element'
            bot_choice = std::distance(rocks.begin(), std::max_element(rocks,rocks.end()));
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2584:1: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator'
      ('std::__1::array<int, 3>' vs. 'int *')
max_element(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2565:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
max_element(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
^
1 error generated.
```

HOWEVER, if I add a zero in the `max_element` arguments for testing, another error appears that, in my opinion, is completely illogical:

```
learning_rps.cpp:30:55: error: no matching function for call to 'max_element'
            bot_choice = std::distance(rocks.begin(), std::max_element(rocks,rocks.end(),0));
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2565:1: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_ForwardIterator'
      ('std::__1::array<int, 3>' vs. 'int *')
max_element(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2584:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
max_element(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
```

So basically if I provide 2 arguments, it says I need 3, but if I provide 3 it says I need 2. I'm very new to c++, so any explanations on why this is erroring and any other optimisations are welcome. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do:

```
bot_choice = std::distance(rocks.begin(), std::max_element(rocks.begin(),rocks.end()));
```

See example section of:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element